# Custom Sequence using Trigger & Sequence in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, function, triggers, sequence

I have a trigger which inserts a custom Sequence (Ref_No.) after every Item(Parent Item) is inserted.
Now I have a sub-Item which is linked to the first item (Parent Item) through Parent Item Id and it can be more than 1.
My trigger for Parent Item generates Sequence as "P2505" and I want my sub-Items Sequence should be "P2505-1", for 2nd Sub-Item it should be "P2505-2" and so on.

also every time a new parent item is inserted the sub-item's sequence should append parent Items Sequence followed by 1 and increment further.

This is my trigger for generating Parent Item's Sequence

```
    create or replace trigger REF_NO_TRIGGER before insert on LOST_ITEM for each row

DECLARE
    PREFIX      VARCHAR2(254);

BEGIN


    SELECT NAME INTO PREFIX FROM SUBCAT WHERE SUBCAT.ID= :NEW.SUBCAT_ID;

   :new.REF_NO := substr(PREFIX,1,1)||(:NEW.CATEGORY_ID)||(:NEW.SUBCAT_ID)||(:NEW.ID);

 end;
```

As per my understanding, I need to check for the parent Item Sequence in Sub-Item table and see if there is any entry , if there is no entry then the first sub item should be ParentItemSequence-1 and then again count and append "-2", "-3" and so on

My Sub-Item Table is "Sub-Item" with a column "Sequence".

Need Help !!!

Comment: What exactly is the question ?

Comment: Your understanding is correct, you need to check the sub-item table, get the maximum entry if there is one, and then increment it by 1.

Comment: @krokodilko
Once my Parent Item is inserted with the Sequence number "P2505" and let's say my parent Item has 3 sub Items, how will I know for which item the Id should be "P2505-1" or "P2505-2" or "P2505-3". For that I need to search for the parent Item Id in the Sub Items Sequence List first and if there is no parent Id in the list by that Sequence then the sequence will be "P2505-1" else "P2505-2" and so on. But I don't know how to achieve that functionality through a trigger because I have to submit all items including Parent and Sub Item at the same time.
Can you help me by an example

Comment: Is this code is expected to run in multiuser/multithreaded environment ?

Comment: @krokodilko  Yes.
There can be multiple users entering items and sub items simultaneously

Comment: In multiuser/multisession environment this solution based on triggers can generate duplicated entries. It depends on expected load, if only one "parent/sub-item" record will be created/inserted not more often than every 1-5 minutes, then this is practically  impossible to get duplicates, but when 10 users will simultaneosly insert 10 parents/items at the same time, you will get a lot of duplicated entries.

Comment: So what should be the solution according to you ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you might generate a ID for a sub-item based upon the parent item's ID:

```
SELECT COALESCE( MAX( TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR(parent_id, '\d+$' ) ) ), 0 ) + 1
  FROM subitem_table;
```

But there is a difficulty here, you can't do this in an INSERT or UPDATE trigger on the subitem table because ... the table is mutating.

Another course of action might be to generate an ID for each sub-item with a sequence/IDENTITY column. Then you can create a view on your sub-item table to generate IDs based on the parent ID in a query:

```
SELECT id, parent_id, parent_id || '-' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY id ) AS subitem_id
  FROM subitem_table;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not able to understand.
Once my Parent Item is inserted with the Sequence number "P2505" and let's say my parent Item has 3 sub Items, how will I know for which item the Id should be "P2505-1" or "P2505-2" or "P2505-3".
For that I need to search for the parent Item Id in the Sub Items Sequence List first and if there is no parent Id in the list by that Sequence then the sequence will be "P2505-1" else "P2505-2" and so on. But I don't know how to achieve that functionality through a trigger because I have to submit all items including Parent and Sub Item at the same time.